# How do I stop losing my object when coming out of orthographic to perspective view while in sculpt mode?

Tags: camera, sculpt-mode

While looking at my model in lets say front view, I make the needed adjustments. Then when i need to then orbit the item the camera seems to always zoom way past the object, causing me to always have to zoom out to see said object. If i am in front view or any ortho view and zoom way out before orbiting the object, this seems to help a little but its not ideal.

I have tried messing around with clip start/end and cant seem to get it. (If this is even the right solution)
I hope i explained my problem well enough. Thank you for the help in advance

Edit: Added picture of navigation [image]
Edit2: Updated to blender 3.5 and still have the same issue

Comment: Can you add an image of your Edit > Preferences > Navigation settings dialog in Blender. That might give us a clue as to what's happening in your case. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: Remember, you can always press Numpad Del (.) to focus on your object from a "sensible" disance.

Comment: thank you @ChristopherBennett - having to press that every time i want to orbit the object doesnt seem too practical. i even have it bound to SHIFT-F. i do use it but it shouldnt be needed